# Print how many pairs of characters in the input line where the first character is less than the second

Tags: java, for-loop, computer-science

Im not sure how to compare the characters char < Char and add the count

it should print
Enter a line:
antidisestablishmentarianism\(whatever the user wants to input)

Your Answer 15

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountRisingPairs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);       
        System.out.println(" Enter a string");      

        String S=in.next();      
        int count;
        int value;
           for (int i=65; i<91; i++) {
              count=0;
              for (int j=0; j<in.length(); j++) {
              value=(int)in[j];
              if (value == i) {
                 count++;
              }
           }
           if (count>0) 
              System.out.println((char)i+" -- "+count);
        }
    }
}
```

i cant use hash map or any other type of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing chars in the input, you should probably keep a variable with the previous char to compare to. I don't think comparing to the index variable *i* is what you want. Then your if statement would be something like

```
if (value > previous) {
    count++;
}
```

Also, when iterating over the input of a Scanner, you should probably do it with a while loop like this:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    // Your counting here
}
```

You need a way to terminate that while loop - you can do that by checking for '\n' or something else. And of course, the while loop can be rewritten as a for loop if you want to.

Comment: other types of loop e.g. while loop not allowed

Answer (score 1):

The loop should iterate over all characters from the first to the next but last so you can compare adjacent characters. They can be compared just like integer values.

```
String s = "antidisestablishmentarianism";
int count = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; ++i ){
    if( s.charAt(i) < s.charAt(i+1) ) count++;
}
System.out.println( "count = " + count );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String element = "antidisestablishmentarianism";

int count = 0;
for (int j=0; j<element.length(); j++)
{
  if(j+1 < element.length()){
    int x = Character.getNumericValue(element.charAt(j));
    int y = Character.getNumericValue(element.charAt(j+1));
    if(x>y){
        count++;
        System.out.println("Pair: "+element.charAt(j)+""+element.charAt(j+1));
    }
  }


}

System.out.println(count+" pairs found");
```

Comment: i implemented your code and it was right. The only thing that was throwing the code off from the prompt was if (x > y) should be <. I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, also closing the scanner using try-with-resources:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountRisingPairs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println(" Enter a string");

            String inputString = in.next();
            int count = 0;
            char previousChar = 100;

            for (char currentChar : inputString.toCharArray()) {
                if (currentChar > previousChar) {
                    count++;
                }
                previousChar = currentChar;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```